# Make rake task from gem available everywhere?

Tags: ruby, rake

So I'm writing a small gem and I have a '/tasks' dir in it with some specific rake tasks. How do I make those tasks available automatically everywhere, where the gem is required? For example I wish I could run 'rake mygemrake:task' inside my rails root dir after I have the gem installed.

Answer (score 22):

For Rails3 applications, you might want to look into making a Railtie for your gem.

You can do so with:

**lib/your_gem/railtie.rb**

```
require 'your_gem'
require 'rails'
module YourGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    rake_tasks do
      require 'path/to/rake.task'
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/your_gem.rb**

```
module YourGem
  require "lib/your_gem/railtie" if defined?(Rails)
end
```

Though, I had my share of difficulties with requiring the `rake.task` file in my `railtie.rb`.  I opted to just define my measley one or two tasks within the `rake_tasks` block.

Comment: Just a word of warning, I couldn't get Rails to require `rake` tasks with a `.rake` extension using this method.

Comment: I think I remember the error being something akin to what's described here:

http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2009/05/26/including-external-rake-files-in-your-projects-rakefile-keep-your-rake-tasks-organized/

perhaps using `import` instead of `require` is the key to success?  I'll dig into this next chance I get a free moment :)

Comment: @BenjaminOakes you could also replace `require` with `load`: `load "path/to/file.rake"`

Comment: Hi all, is there a way for creating a rake task without requiring rails?

Comment: @nisevi it's perfectly fine to create rake task without requiring Rails, e.g. https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/blob/master/lib/sitemap_generator/railtie.rb

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [rdoctask](http://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/783adcadb3e6b6c8052ff1f71a6428da45c31d32/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb) in rake for an example of how to define a task provided by a gem. The task is defined in ruby instead of the rake build language and can be required like so:

```
require 'rake'             # the gem
require 'rake/rdoctask'    # the task
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what [Sake](http://errtheblog.com/posts/60-sake-bomb) is for. Datamapper and Merb have been using Sake with success.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import those tasks in application's Rakefile. This is how it looks in mine (I am using bundler08 to manage my gems):

```
%w(gem1 gem2 gem3).each do |g|
  Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/vendor/bundler_gems/**/#{g}*/tasks/*.rake"].each do |f|
    import f
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write normal rake tasks for a gem and load them like this:

```
require 'rake'
load 'path/to/your/tasks.rake'
```

Also, take a look at [thor vs. rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524296/rake-vs-thor-for-automation-scripts).