# Simple pattern to export rake tasks defined in gem to the outside world upon installation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rake-task

This question follows the "[Make rake task from gem available everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742633/make-rake-task-from-gem-available-everywhere)" for which I'm not fully satisfied with the Railties approach since it induces a dependency on Rails3 which seems to me overkilling compared to what I want. 
Also, I dislike the idea to create an extra binary as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858495/ruby-accessing-rake-task-from-a-gem-without-rails)

So, assuming I have the below layout:

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── LICENCE.md
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── my_gem.gemspec
├── lib
│   ├── my_gem
│   │   ├── common.rb
│   │   ├── loader.rb
│   │   ├── tasks
│   │   │   └── sometasks.rake
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── my_gem.rb
```

where `lib/my_gem/tasks/sometasks.rake` has some nested rake tasks definition:

```
#.....................
namespace :n1 do
    #.....................
    namespace :n2 do

        desc "Tasks n1:n2:t1"
        task :t1 do |t|
            puts "Task 1"
        end

        desc "Tasks n1:n2:t2"
        task :t2 do |t|
            puts "Task 2"
        end

    end # namespace n1:n2
end # namespace n1
```

How can I easily share these tasks in another external `Rakefile` with a simple syntax such as `require "my_gem/sometasks"` once the gem is installed?

I tested the following configuration in a separate directory with success yet I still think it's a complicated syntax. Any help to simplify the load / include/ require would be welcome:

- add a `GemFile` containing

  `gem 'my_gem', :path => '~/path/to/my_gem'`
- add a `Rakefile` with the following content:

  ```
  require "my_gem"
  load "my_gem/tasks/sometasks.rake"

  desk "Test my_gem"
  task :toto do |t|
  puts "task toto"
  end
  ```

In the above configuration, it works:

```
$> bundle exec rake -T
 rake n1:n2:t1       # Task n1:n2:t1
 rake n1:n2:t1       # Task n1:n2:t2
 rake toto           # Test my_gem
```

Yet if I get rid of `.rake` extension in the `Rakefile`, I have a load error

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- my_gem/tasks/sometasks
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 4):

I found a way, inspired from [Bundler](https://github.com/bundler/bundler) to offer a simplified interface (and `[gem_tasks.rb](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/gem_tasks.rb)`:

- create a file `lib/my_gem/sometasks_tasks.rb` with an `install_tasks` method

  ```
  require 'rake'

  module MyGem
    class SomeTasks
      include Rake::DSL if defined? Rake::DSL
      def install_tasks
         load 'my_gem/tasks/sometasks.rake'
      end
    end 
  end 
  MyGem::SomeTasks.new.install_tasks
  ```
- In the application’s `Rakefile`, it is now enough to add `require 'my_gem/sometasks_tasks'`